# Placed Marker on GoogleMapSDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am successfully draw polyline between two points. But i want to put source point to left side of map and destination point to right side of map and draw line horizontally between them.

Any idea is really appreciated.

```
- (void)addMarkerOnMap {

NSArray* arrMarkerData = @[
                           @{@"icon":[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue"], @"position":[[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:self.pickupAddCoordinate.latitude longitude:self.pickupAddCoordinate.longitude]},
                           @{@"icon":[UIImage imageNamed:@"yellow"], @"position":[[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:self.destinationAddCordinate.latitude longitude:self.destinationAddCordinate.longitude]}
                           ];

GMSCoordinateBounds *bounds = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc] init];

//*> Including current location coordinate
bounds = [bounds includingCoordinate:[LocationManager sharedManager].currentCoordinate];

for (NSDictionary *dict in arrMarkerData)
{        
    //*> Add a marker in the center of the map.

    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.icon       = (UIImage *)dict[@"icon"];
    marker.position   = [(CLLocation *)dict[@"position"] coordinate];
    bounds            = [bounds includingCoordinate:marker.position];
    marker.map        = self.mapView;

}

//*> Fit Marker in bound    
if (self.isZoomMapView)
{
    [self.mapView animateWithCameraUpdate:[GMSCameraUpdate fitBounds:bounds withPadding:25.0f]];
    self.isZoomMapView = NO;
}

[self.mapView animateToBearing:-75];
[self getPathGoogleAPI_CallWithSource:self.pickupAddCoordinate andDestination:self.destinationAddCordinate];}
```

This Method for Polyline

```
- (void)getPathGoogleAPI_CallWithSource : (CLLocationCoordinate2D)sourceCoordinate andDestination: (CLLocationCoordinate2D)destinationCoordinate
{

    NSString *getDriverLocationURl;    
    NSDictionary *postParams = @{k_API_GoogleOrigin      : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", sourceCoordinate.latitude, sourceCoordinate.longitude],
                                 k_API_GoogleDestination : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f",                                                          destinationCoordinate.latitude, destinationCoordinate.longitude],
                                };

    getDriverLocationURl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", GOOGLE_DIRECTION_URL];

    [serviceManager apiCallUsingDataTaskHTTPMethod:GET url:getDriverLocationURl andParameters:postParams forTask:kTaskDrawRoute currentView:self.view accessToken:NO completionHandler:^(id response, NSError *error, TaskType task, BOOL success)
    {
        if (!error && response)
        {
            if ([[response valueForKey:RESPONSE_STATUS] isEqualToString:RESPONSE_OK])
            {
                NSArray *routArr            = [response valueForKey:k_API_GoogleRoutes];

                GMSPath *path = [GMSPath pathFromEncodedPath:routArr[0][@"overview_polyline"][@"points"]];
                polyline = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
                polyline.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];
                polyline.strokeWidth = 4.f;
                polyline.map = self.mapView;
            }
            else
            {
                DLog(@"Google Direction : %@", [response valueForKey:RESPONSE_ERROR_MESSAGE]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            DLog(@"Google Direction : Sorry something went wrong");
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: You can use two image icons to mark(one for source and another for destination).

Comment: i already apply this. i just want to show polyline  from left to right.

Comment: Then whats the issue  can u explain briefly.

Comment: the source marker always in left side of map & destination right side. hope this make sense.

Comment: Add ground anchor:

CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.5, -0.127);
CLLocationDegrees degrees = 90;
GMSMarker *london = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];
london.groundAnchor = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
london.rotation = degrees;
london.map = mapView_;

Answer (score 1):

To make marker icon center allingned use Ground Anchor.

```
_marker1 = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
_marker1.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(12.9716, 77.5946);
_marker1.title = @"sydney";
_marker1.groundAnchor = CGPointMake(0.2, 0.9);
_marker1.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;
_marker1.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;
_marker1.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Flag Filled -50.png"];
```

Vary ground anchor point to make it center

Comment: no its not working.i want to place a marker in such a way, so polyline always draw horizontal

Comment: Marker placing is not working or to draw polyline horizontally is not working.can u explain

Comment: polyline draw horizontally

Comment: poly line depends points that you are assigning to GMSmutablepath.if u assign two lat longs horizontal then poly line is horizontal.

Comment: plz add code snippet in your question  that will help to answer your question accurately.

Comment: how to assign lat long horizontal to GMSMutable path.

Comment: Like below you can add lat long

 _path = [GMSMutablePath path];
    [_path addLatitude:12.9716 longitude:77.5946]; // bangalore
    [_path addLatitude:13.3710 longitude:76.6413]; // tumkur
    [_path addLatitude:15.3173 longitude:75.7139]; // mysore
    [_path addLatitude:15.3647 longitude:75.1240]; //Hubli

Comment: can you show code and where you mention its horizontal.

Comment: If your location latitudes and longitudes are on horizontal line you will get horizontal polyline.

Comment: how can it be possible .if varying locations  are at different angle from the current location.

Comment: yes this is the point you always have to set map (by rotating or any other way) so it always looks in horizontal manner. you take any two points on map and using your fingers to set it horizontally.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109812/discussion-between-prabhat-and-kumar-swamy).

Answer (score 0):

Horizontal poly line is purely depended on latitude value. if two location latitude values are same than poly line is horizontal.
[image: poly line horizontallu]

```
 _path = [GMSMutablePath path];
[_path addLatitude:12.9716 longitude:77.5946]; // bangalore
[_path addLatitude:12.9716 longitude:78.0]; // tumkur


_marker1 = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
_marker1.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(12.9716, 77.5946);
_marker1.title = @"Bangalore";
_marker1.groundAnchor = CGPointMake(0.2, 0.9);
_marker1.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;
_marker1.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;
_marker1.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Flag Filled -50.png"];
_marker1.snippet = @"India";
_marker1.map = _mapView;

_marker2 = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
_marker2.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(12.9716, 78.0);
_marker2.title = @"Tumkur";
_marker2.groundAnchor = CGPointMake(0.3, 0.9);
_marker2.snippet = @"India";
_marker2.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Flag Filled -50.png"];
_marker2.map = _mapView;
_polyline = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:_path];
_polyline.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];
_polyline.strokeWidth = 1.f;
_polyline.path = _path;
_polyline.map = _mapView;
```